# Pass javascript parameter to partial view in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

lets say I want to a partial view like the following sample

```
@Html.RenderAction("ListDocuments", "MultiFileAttachments", new { id = jsparameter });
```

in the jsparameter I want to pass as a parameter that is the result of a javascript function. Maybe this is not logical because javascript runs on the client, but how can I achieve a similar functionality ? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to call a part of a page based on some actions or values determined by actions on the client side, then you should think to use JavaScript (preferably [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) and [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

Through [jQuery-Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you could easily call a Partial view through the Contoler and since it's a regular HTTP request, you would be able to pass all the parameters you need.

Using code as :

```
@Html.RenderAction("ListDocuments", "MultiFileAttachments", new { id = jsparameter });
```

is not possible since it is rendered by the server before it's sent to the client browser.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to pass the javascript value like this, because the value comes from the selection of a row (from a kendo grid) by the user. I just wanted to make sure there is no other way to achieve this other than jQuery. Thank you for the answer...